# How to insert a column into a data frame with values based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that is made with this:

```
df <- structure(list(samples = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("LAIV D0",
"LAIV D3", "LAIV D7", "TIV D0", "TIV D3", "TIV D7"), class = "factor"),
    celltype = structure(c(1L, 1L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Neutrophil",
    "Tcell", "Monocyte", "Bcell", "NKcell", "PlasmaCell", "DendriticCell"
    ), class = "factor"), score = c("0.1620678925564", "-0.0609851972808482",
    "0.198920574361332", "-0.106111265294409")), .Names = c("samples",
"celltype", "score"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 1140L, 1141L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

```
> df
     samples      celltype               score
1    LAIV D0    Neutrophil     0.1620678925564
2    LAIV D3    Neutrophil -0.0609851972808482
1140  TIV D3 DendriticCell   0.198920574361332
1141  TIV D7 DendriticCell  -0.106111265294409
```

What I want to do is to insert a column `status` based on substring in `samples`.
If `LAIV` exist in string under `samples` then status is *control*. If `TIV` status is *treated*.

So in the end it'll look like this:

```
     samples      celltype               score  status 
1    LAIV D0    Neutrophil     0.1620678925564  control
2    LAIV D3    Neutrophil -0.0609851972808482  control
1140  TIV D3 DendriticCell   0.198920574361332  treated
1141  TIV D7 DendriticCell  -0.106111265294409  treated
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could combine `grepl()` with `ifelse()` like this:

```
df$status <- ifelse(grepl("LAIV", df$samples), "control", "treated")
#> df
#     samples      celltype               score  status
#1    LAIV D0    Neutrophil     0.1620678925564 control
#2    LAIV D3    Neutrophil -0.0609851972808482 control
#1140  TIV D3 DendriticCell   0.198920574361332 treated
#1141  TIV D7 DendriticCell  -0.106111265294409 treated
```

---

If the data contains observations that don't qualify as "control" or "treated", like a third or a missing category, it is better to assign the values separately instead of using `ifelse()`:

```
df$status[grepl("LAIV",df$samples)] <- "control"
df$status[grepl("TIV",df$samples)] <- "treated"
```

For the sample data the result is the same.